# AVPlayerViewController inside a view is not showing the playback controls

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, tvos, avplayerviewcontroller

I am working with apple tv. I have a UIView inside my UIViewController. I am adding AVPlayerViewController as subview of my UIView. UIView's frame is CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 1344, height: 756). I am setting AVPlayerViewController frame equals to my UIView's frame.

**Issue is that video plays fine in its frame but the controls like pause, play, forward etc. are hidden and not working. But when I set frame as CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1920, height: 1080), controls are visible and working.**

**My code is as per below:**

```
    let url = URL(string: "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")
    let item = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)        
    self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
    self.avplayerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    self.avplayerController.player = self.player
    self.avplayerController.view.frame = videoPreviewLayer.frame
    self.avplayerController.showsPlaybackControls = true
    self.avplayerController.requiresLinearPlayback = true

    self.addChildViewController(self.avplayerController)
    self.view.addSubview(self.avplayerController.view)

    self.avpController.player?.play()
```

Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an expected behaviour:

> AVPlayerViewController is designed such that when in full screen, the
>   full playback experience (scrubbing, info panel access, etc) are all
>   available. When in a space less than full screen, the assumption is
>   that it is just one of several interactive elements on screen, and
>   thus the view should not absorb all touch surface events as transport
>   control.

You can read more about this on this thread: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/19526

Comment: Hey thanks for clearance David. Is that any way I can show controls for avplayer when space is less than full screen?

Comment: @Ruchi yes you can do it adding your custom views over an instance of AVPlayer, getting info out of AVPlayer properties, but it is not possible making use of a native AVPlayerViewController.

Comment: Ok. Do you know any third party library or framework for that? I searched but couldn't get a single one.

Answer (score 9):

I managed to solve this using this code:

```
let player = AVPlayer(url: self.videoUrl!)
let avPlayerController = AVPlayerViewController()

avPlayerController.player = player;
avPlayerController.view.frame = self.videoPlayView.bounds;

self.addChildViewController(avPlayerController)
self.videoPlayView.addSubview(avPlayerController.view);
```

Now AVPlayerViewController shows **most** playback controls even as child to a uiview.

Courtesy: 
https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_8_Video_Playback_using_AVPlayer_and_AVPlayerViewController

Comment: I used this in collection view that is in table view cell The controls are showing But don't work for me

Comment: @SaeedRahmatolahi Were you able to solve this?

Comment: @RajeshBudhiraja I used scroll view instead of collection View in my case and I could see the buttons