# How to correctly displayed on the UITableViewCell a AVPlayerViewController?

Tags: ios, uitableview, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

When I perform the following code, AVPlayerViewController will be displayed on the cell, but when I click on the player again, will perform tableView: (UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.What I want is when the video is playing, click on the player, will show or hide controlls instead of performing tableView: (UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
-(void)showVideoInView:(UIView *)view URL:(NSURL *)url {
if (!url || !view) {
    return;
}

CGRect frame = CGRectIntegral(view.bounds);

UIViewController *video;

if (@available(iOS 8.0,*)) {
    AVPlayerViewController * videoController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
    videoController.view.frame = frame;
    videoController.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
    if (@available(iOS 10.0,*)) {
        videoController.player.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = NO;
    }
    [videoController.player play];
    video = videoController;
}else {
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *videoController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
    videoController.view.frame = frame;
    [[videoController moviePlayer] play];
    video = videoController;
}
   [view addSubview:video.view];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, AVPlayers don't show the video controls when they are not full screen. You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42994749/avplayerviewcontroller-inside-a-view-is-not-showing-the-playback-controls).

Instead you can add a touch gesture to the video player and add the play pause buttons accordingly. Maybe customize a bit.
Also remember to reuse the cells else they will mess you the video playback.
You may also want to remember the seek bar position, in case you reuse the cell.